# Returning a list of user friends in facebook graph api using php

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble (yet again) with returning a list of friends for a specific user. This is the code:

```
   $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
 echo $friends;
```

However, it does not display anything on the page at all. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, you have to provide active access token. If I remember correctly you need special permission to see user's friend list too.

```
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();  $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends', 
                          'GET', 
                           array (
                             'access_token' => $token));
```

Update:
Friends lists are included with the basic permissions. The [Facebook API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends) says:

> **Read**
>
> You can read the list of a User's friends by issuing an `HTTP
>   GET` to `/PROFILE_ID/friends` with any valid access_token of the current
>   session user. For example:
>
> `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`

Comment: Thank you. If I had the ability to give you rep I would.